# What is the difference between copying text inside a <span> and inside a heading?

Tags: html, copy, clipboard, copy-paste

Consider the following markup -

```
<h1 class="foo">
    <span>Heading Text</span>
</h1>

<p class="foo">
    <span>Paragraph Text</span>
</p>
```

When `Heading Text` is selected and copied, the entire `h1` element is copied to the clipboard, but when selecting and copying `Paragraph Text` only the `span` element is copied to the clipboard (possibly inside a new paragraph element, so the class is lost)

Why is there a difference in the copy behavior? The selection is selecting the text node, the only difference is the parent element.

Is there a way around it? Can I force the parent element to be copied along with the paragraph's text node without tempering with Selection API?

Tested on Chrome under both Windows and OSX